# Django block repeated requests

Tags: django, brute-force, broken-links

I get 5-7 requests in the same time (different IPs) each 20 minutes. The requested URL existed before but it's not there anymore. It seems something like a brute force to me.

What should I do about it?

How can I tell django to not send me broken link emails for this request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To stop broken emails, add the url you wish to ignore to your `IGNORABLE_404_URLS` setting.

See the [Django error reporting docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/error-reporting/#errors) for more info.